# why there is an error when executing the fork() system call?

Tags: c++, c

there is an error when trying to executing the fork() call.
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration fork();
here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    b = fork();
    printf("hello");
    if (b == 0)
    {
        printf("child");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("parent");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and try to find out whether you are using C or C++.

Comment: Because you don't include the header fork is declared in, which is `unistd.h`.

Comment: `fork` _is_ implicitly declared because you need to do `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: That error is supposed to arise when compiling the code, not when executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ## try this code##
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  int main()
{
    int a;
    pid_t b;
    b = fork();
   printf("HELLO");
   if (b == 0)
   {
      printf("child");
   }
   else
   {
    printf("parent");
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    pid_t b;
    b = fork();
    printf("hello");
    if (b == 0)
    {
        printf("child");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("parent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the error `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` is only thrown when the method or function that you're trying to use has not been defined in any of the headers that have been included.

e.g: trying to use `printf` without including `stdio.h`

The fork function is included from `unistd.h`.